# what wrong with my binary compression with C#

Tags: c#, compression, deflate

I try to compress some binary string with deflate32 but something is going wrong.

```
string myString = "101111110101010111111111111";
// convert string to stream
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
var compressed = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
Console.WriteLine(compressed); // Can't see any compressed string
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What are you expecting Console.WriteLine of a stream object to show, other than `System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream`? Even after you fix it by reading the stream into a byte array, converting the byte array to a string, and printing the string.. what are you expecting shall appear in the console, other than a garbled mix of printable/substitution characters?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10599797/18452174

Comment: And BTW: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString)` is probably not what you intended, it will produce a byte array like `{ 0x31, 0x30, 0x31, ... }` (0x31 is the UTF8 code for '1')

Comment: @KlausGütter -  So what is the best encoding for binary string?

Comment: Your code is backwards.  You are trying to compress and instead you are deflating : var compressed = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Fastest);

Comment: You need to read from the DeflateStream instead of write the class instance to the console.

Comment: "encoding for binary string" - I do not understand what this means. What is the expected result?